# How to split dask dataframe into partitions based on unique values in a column?

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I have a dask dataframe with a date column `doc_date` that is in the range `12-1-2021` to `1-2-2022`. I want to repartition and split this dask dataframe into the 26 partitions such that each partition has only 1 of the dates in the aforementioned date range.

Here's what I tried:

```
doc_dates = [dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for dt in pd.date_range('2021-12-08', '2022-01-02')]
predictions_df = predictions_df.set_index('doc_date')
predictions_df = predictions_df.repartition(divisions=sorted(doc_dates))
```

But I appear to be getting this error:

```
ValueError: left side of old and new divisions are different
```

Comment: Does this help?: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2489

Comment: @alirezafnatica that issue was resolved four years ago, so unlikely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you need to pass `compute=True` to [`dask.dataframe.set_index`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.set_index.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.set_index) to ensure that the data is actually sorted by date before you can provide the sorted list of dates to the `repartition` command:

```py
predictions_df = predictions_df.set_index('doc_date', compute=True)
predictions_df = predictions_df.repartition(divisions=sorted(doc_dates))
```

Alternatively, you can use the `divisions` argument to [`dask.dataframe.set_index`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.set_index.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.set_index):

```py
predictions_df = predictions_df.set_index(
    'doc_date',
    divisions=sorted(doc_dates),
    compute=True,
)
```