# Create new column in Dask DataFrame with specific value for each partition

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe, dask-delayed

I have two Dask DataFrames with the same number of partitions.

The first one has few columns and few rows for each partition (so Pandas DataFrame), but the number of rows could differs between two partitions (not the columns).
The second Dask DataFrame has exactly the same number of partitions but have only 1 value.
I'm trying to merge these 2 Dask DataFrames by merging, partition to partition like below.

Dask DataFrame N°1 (toy example):

[image]

Dask DataFrame N°2 (with only 1 value per partition and so only 1 column):

[image]

And my aim is to obtain a Dask Dataframe like this :

[image]

I tried `Dask.assign()` with `Dask.map_partitions()` but without success.

Do you have an idea to make this efficently ?

Regards.

rmarion37

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70587191/991710)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer,

To fulfill all the rows for each partition the key point, in the delayed function, is to force the value as a integer (for my example).
It's for sure a special tweak from Pandas, not very clear in the docuementation but real !!!

```
@dask.delayed def process_partitions(partition1, partition2):  
    partition1.loc[:, 'id_cycle'] = int(partition2)
    return partition1

delayeds = []
for partition1, partition2 in zip(ddf1.partitions, ddf2.partitions):
    delayeds.append(process_partitions(partition1, partition2))

ddf3 = from_delayed(delayeds)
ddf = ddf3.compute()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that the number of partitions and their order are the same for two dataframes, it's possible to create a custom procedure that processes these partitions in pairs:

```py
from dask import delayed
from dask.dataframe import from_delayed

@delayed
def process_partitions(partition1, partition2):
    ...
    # for example:
    # merged = partition1.merge(partition2)
    # return merged

# assume ddf1, ddf2 have the same number/order of partitions
delayeds = []
for partition1, partition2 in zip(ddf1.partitions, ddf2.partitions):
    delayeds.append(process_partitions(partition1, partition2))

ddf3 = from_delayed(delayeds)
```

Comment: Thanks,

I tried :  

```
@dask.delayed
def process_partitions(partition1, partition2):
    partition1.loc[:, 'z'] = partition2
    return partition1

delayeds = []
for partition1, partition2 in zip(ddf1.partitions, ddf2.partitions):
    delayeds.append(process_partitions(partition1, partition2))

ddf3 = from_delayed(delayeds)
ddf = ddf3.compute()
print(ddf)
```  

I have this result :  

  x    y     z  
0  1  1.0  10.0  
1  2  2.0   NaN  
2  3  3.0   NaN  
3  4  4.0   NaN  
4  5  5.0   NaN

Only the fist line of the first partition is added.

Regards.

Rémy

Comment: Hello, Remy, to me it looks like your `process_partitions` function is not defined correctly. Test it with pandas to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: Yes for sure, it's a problem with `process_partitions` function. I understood that the Dask partitions are individual Pandas DataFrame but even if I use solution OK with Pandas, it doesn't work on Dask Partitions. I tested `insert`, `assign` without success. Very strange ..